# Pandas dataframe unique values column merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-merge

I'm still learning data manipulation with Pandas and this is the problem which occurred:

Trying to merge two dataframes:

Creating the first one with a string filter

```
df_mask1 = df[eval(mask1)].groupby(['Country', 'ID']).agg({'Serial': 'count'}).reset_index()
```

the result looks like this

[image]

and doing the same with the second filter creating a second df

```
df_mask2 = df[eval(mask2)].groupby(['Country', 'ID']).agg({'Serial': 'count'}).reset_index()
```

[image]

and merging the two and filling missing values

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df_mask1, df_mask2, on=['Country', 'ID'], how='outer', suffixes=('_count_1', '_count_2'))
merged_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

and the result looks like this

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is having unique values for the Country and ID columns pair. In plain words I need 1 row for ID 88888 which have value 93.0 for Serial_count_1 and 1.0 for Serial_count_2.

Any comments and suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: The example you have given isn't really that helpful towards us providing you an answer.  You say 1 row for ID 88888, 93.0 1.0 but ID 88888 is shared between Kenya and Pakistan. So if you want to give each country a unique ID you would assume Kenya 11111 and Pakistan 88888 but then you say 93.0 and 1.0 values but they belong to different countries. Please provide an expected output example.

Comment: Do you want `merged_df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).sum()`?

Comment: What is the value of the Country?  as you have Kenya and Pakistan with same ID : 88888!

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I realized the problem is not with manipulation but in the raw input data - ID should not be shared between countries.